# Why am I getting a crash when using react-native-linear-gradient ONLY on iOS 17+

Tags: ios, react-native, linear-gradients

I've been noticing a ton of new crashes over the last few weeks coming into AppStoreConnect relating to LinearGradient which I have imported from react-native-linear-gradient

These crash logs ONLY have iOS 17+ so I am guessing it has something to do with a change that happened in the upgrade, but don't really care much about that change, I just want to know how to fix it in my app and prevent the crash.

Here's a simplified reproducible version of my component, a bar which animates from the left to the right, which runs fine on iOS 16 and below but crashes on 17+ with no logs in the terminal

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Animated } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

const AnimatedGradient = ({ credit = 0 }) => {
  const [barWidth, setBarWidth] = useState(1);
  const position = new Animated.Value(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(position, {
      toValue: credit,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  }, [credit]);

  const animatedWidth = position.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, barWidth],
  });

  return (
    <View onLayout={(event) => setBarWidth(event.nativeEvent.layout.width)}>
      <Animated.View style={{ width: animatedWidth }}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['blue', 'darkblue']}
          start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
          end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}
          style={{ height: 10 }}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default AnimatedGradient;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some painful debugging I found out that on all iOS 17+ versions, create a react-native-linear-gradient with a width of 0 causes a hard crash of the app.  This is a bug that should be filed with their package ASAP.

this change in the code above fixes the issue- note the range now goes from 1 to barWidth instead of starting at 0

```
const animatedWidth = position.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [1, barWidth],
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

you must update react-native-linear-gradient to v2.8.3 to avoid this crash, this crash belong to `NSInternalInconsistencyException`

see more here : https://github.com/react-native-linear-gradient/react-native-linear-gradient/issues/637#issuecomment-1725219069